# Focus events on IE 11 on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to catch focus in and focus out on the entire web page.
I am using:

```
function focus_in(){
  console.log("focus");
}

function focus_out(){
  console.log("blur");
}

window.addEventListener("focus", focus_in, false);
window.addEventListener("blur", focus_out, false);
```

and it is working well on Chrome.
However on Windows 7 with IE 11 10 the focus event is being followed by an unwanted blur event.

I have tried:

```
window.onfocusout = focus_out
window.onfocusin = focus_in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the debug window (console) is gaining focus whenever it is being written on, so whenever I wrote focus on the console it immediately lost focus as well.

Answer (score 1):

In IE, you will have to use the document's `focusin` and `focusout` events:

```
document.addEventListener("focusin", function() { console.log("focusin"); }, false);
document.addEventListener("focusout", function() { console.log("focusout"); }, false);
```

Comment: @Meschiany for me, it works perfectly. Have you forgotten to disable other event listeners?